# Bootstrap 4 Carousel: How to stack container items instead of inline

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

Wanting to stack the contents of each slide (an h2 and button) vertically instead of the default inline format of Bootstrap 4 Carousel. My code is as follows:

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url({{ 'placeholder1.jpg' | asset_url }})">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <h2>Great food without the price</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Order now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[Current default format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saGmF.png)

[Desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkgYw.png)

This is my first time using version 4 so a little fresh on use of d-flex etc. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.flex-column` to your `.d-flex` div. But also need to put some `<br>` tag inside `<h2>` as to seperate the text into two lines.

Comment: Thank you so much. The br in the h2 was omitted mistakenly in example, but the .flex-column worked a treat. Now to study up these flex classes!

Comment: You can check out CSS-Tricks to know more about flex box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/